# Android Development: Is it possible to retain a file even after a 'Clear Data'?

Tags: android, file, persistence

Can an Android application leave a file behind for traceability and not have it removed if a user performs a 'Clear Data'? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Save the file on the internal memory or sdcard in a folder named after your app or anything.This might help. [Saving Files | Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#WriteInternalStorage)

Comment: 'Clear Data' will remove a file created internally by File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), filename);

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes and no. You can save a file to the SD card. As @DegreatYartey wrote, you can look at [Environment class documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()) to see how it can be done. An example would be:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + theFileName;
File file = new File(path);
```

On the other hand, the answer is no, as there is no guarantee the file will be retained. The user (or other apps that have the proper permission) can manually delete it any time they wish. This means that even without clearing the data the file may be deleted.

One other concern is that in case the user will uninstall the app, your file might stay in the external location forever and that is not very nice to the user.

Bottom line, you need to carefully think before using this method.

Comment: I'm ok if the user removes the file manually. I respect the user's space. The file is just a marker of size 0. And as denoted above the [Saving Files | Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html) instructions does not help retain file after a 'Clear Data'.

Comment: I added an example from a different source that should work. Be sure to have the right permissions when you use it (WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE).